# Verilog Vending machine FSM

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I am trying to build a finite state machine in verilog for a vending machine that accepts 5,10, 25 cents as inputs and then output a a soda or diet and also output the appropriate change(as the number of nickels). I am currently getting an error that says ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Xilinx Stuff/FSM/FSM.v" Line 128: Syntax error near "endmodule".
I am fairly new to verilog and whilst I get that this is probably a silly error like forgetting a semi-colon or something, I just cannot for the life of me find it. My code is below:

```
module FSM(quarter, nickel, dime, soda, diet,clk, reset, change_count, give_soda,give_diet);
    input quarter, nickel, dime, soda, diet,clk, reset,give_soda,give_diet;
    output change_count;
    reg[3:0] current_state, next_state;
    parameter cent0 = 0, cent5= 1, cent10 = 2, cent15=3, cent20 =4, cent25 =5, cent30=6,cent35=7,cent40=8;

    always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
        begin
            if(reset)
            begin
                current_state = cent0;
            end
            else
                current_state = next_state;
        end

    always @(current_state | ((quarter ^ nickel) ^ dime))
        begin
        case(current_state)
            cent0: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent5;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent10;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent25;
                end
            cent5: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent10;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent15;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent30;
                end
            cent10: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent15;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent20;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent35;
                end
            cent15: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent20;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent25;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent40;
                end
            cent20: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent25;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent30;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        if(soda)    
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                end
                cent25: begin
                    if(nickel)  
                            next_state = cent30;
                    else if(dime)
                            next_state = cent35;
                    else if(quarter)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            change_count = 1;
                            if(soda)    
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    end
                cent30: begin
                    if(nickel)
                            next_state = cent35;
                    else if(dime)
                            next_state = cent40;
                    else if(quarter)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            change_count = 2;
                            if(soda)    
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    end
                cent35: begin
                    if(nickel)
                            next_state = cent40;
                    else if(dime)
                            next_state = cent40;
                    else if(quarter)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            change_count = 2;
                            if(soda)
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    end
                cent40: begin
                    if(nickel)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            if(soda)
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    else if(dime)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            change_count = 1;
                            if(soda)
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    else if(quarter)
                            next_state = cent0;
                            change_count = 4;
                            if(soda)
                                    give_soda = 1;
                            else if(diet)
                                    give_diet = 1;
                    end
                default: next_state = current_state;
                endcase


endmodule
```

Comment: it looks like your second always doesn't have a matching `end` for its `begin`.

Comment: my only other advice is that you should separate your next state logic from your output logic. although it wont help much with Xilinix (some HDL compilers care) it helps a ton with readability.

Comment: To balance between area cost and module speed you can change state encoding to one-hot. This is implementation of a small algorithm. In case of bigger implementation can be used Compostional Microprogram Control Unit methodology:

https://books.google.pl/books?id=AvX60naUVBgC&pg=PA65&dq=compositional+microprogram+control+unit&hl=pl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=compositional%20microprogram%20control%20unit&f=false

http://zbc.uz.zgora.pl/Content/14668/R.Wisniewski%20-%20PhD%20Thesis.pdf

http://www.pe.org.pl/articles/2014/12/6.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using:

```
always @(current_state | ((quarter ^ nickel) ^ dime))
```

the standard coding style would be to use:

```
always @(current_state or quarter or nickel or dime)
```

With Verilog 2001 or System Verilog you can use a comma separated sensitivity list as follows:

```
always @(current_state, quarter, nickel, dime)
```

Finally in verilog 2001 and later, you can use a wildcard for combinatorial logic always blocks:

```
always @(*)
```

If you need to debounce your inputs or make sure no more than one of the coin signals is asserted at a time, that should probably be done outside of the state machine.

Comment: yeah it was so the state machine would ignore multiple button presses on the fpga but that was before I knew what a debouncer was. Thanks!

Comment: In relation to the wildcard for the combinational logic, how do you actually chose what the "*" represents. I'm just a little confused on what the * actually means

Comment: The * indicates that any signal referenced on the right hand side of an equation in the always block is included in the sensitivity list.

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is the correct verilog code,

module FSM(quarter, nickel, dime, soda, diet,clk, reset, current_state, next_state, change_count, give_soda, give_diet);
input quarter, nickel, dime, soda, diet,clk, reset;
output [3:0] current_state; 
 output next_state, change_count, give_soda, give_diet;
reg current_state, change_count, next_state, give_soda, give_diet;
parameter cent0 = 0, cent5= 1, cent10 = 2, cent15=3, cent20 =4, cent25 =5, cent30=6,cent35=7,cent40=8;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            current_state = cent0;
        else
            current_state = next_state;
    end

always @(nickel or dime or quarter)
    begin
    case(current_state)
        cent0: begin
            if(nickel)  
                    next_state = cent5;
            else if(dime)
                    next_state = cent10;
            else if(quarter)
                    next_state = cent25;
            end
        cent5: begin
            if(nickel)  
                    next_state = cent10;
            else if(dime)
                    next_state = cent15;
            else if(quarter)
                    next_state = cent30;
            end
        cent10: begin
            if(nickel)  
                    next_state = cent15;
            else if(dime)
                    next_state = cent20;
            else if(quarter)
                    next_state = cent35;
            end
        cent15: begin
            if(nickel)  
                    next_state = cent20;
            else if(dime)
                    next_state = cent25;
            else if(quarter)
                    next_state = cent40;
            end
        cent20: begin
            if(nickel)  
                    next_state = cent25;
            else if(dime)
                    next_state = cent30;
            else if(quarter)
                    next_state = cent0;
                    if(soda)    
                            give_soda = 1;
                    else if(diet)
                            give_diet = 1;
            end
            cent25: begin
                if(nickel)  
                        next_state = cent30;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent35;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        change_count = 1;
                        if(soda)    
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                end
            cent30: begin
                if(nickel)
                        next_state = cent35;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent40;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        change_count = 2;
                        if(soda)    
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                end
            cent35: begin
                if(nickel)
                        next_state = cent40;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent40;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        change_count = 2;
                        if(soda)
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                end
            cent40: begin
                if(nickel)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        if(soda)
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                else if(dime)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        change_count = 1;
                        if(soda)
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                else if(quarter)
                        next_state = cent0;
                        change_count = 4;
                        if(soda)
                                give_soda = 1;
                        else if(diet)
                                give_diet = 1;
                end
            default: next_state = current_state;
            endcase
end

endmodule
```